# Ajax Upload many files, possible?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, upload, controls

I am searching for a control that looks very nice and give support to upload 3-5 files at ones.
Ajax would be nice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Uploadify which flexible and supports multiple files as well. With very nice interface.

http://www.uploadify.com/

And to use it with asp.net:

http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/45/asp.net-c-code-to-replace-upload.php-upload.ashx/p1

Answer (score 1):

uploadify is awesome [check it out](http://www.uploadify.com)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery MultiFile plugin does exactly that.  You will need to write some backend code to handle the posted files, but this should get you started:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/MultiFile